# jQuery detect child <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, menu, toggle

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="http://google.com">Text</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://google.com">Text</a>
        <li><a href="#">Text</a>
        <li><a href="#">Text</a>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://google.com">Text</a></li>
<li><a href="http://google.com">Text</a></li>
<li><a href="http://google.com">Text</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Text</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Text</a>
        <li><a href="#">Text</a>
        <li><a href="#">Text</a>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(".menu li a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find("ul").toggle();
    return false;
});
```

**How to make this js work only when `<li>` has `<ul>` inside it?**

Without adding extra classes.

It should not work when there is no child `<ul>` inside current `<li>`.

**Example of this available on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/bXbnW/)**

Its better if you give link to your working example.

Comment: What do you want it to do when there *is* a child `ul`?

Comment: @David Thomas, if there is a child <ul> inside current <li>, when we click on first link inside current list item, <ul> should become visible (toggle effect). Otherwise we don't do anything (no js for this list item).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try restricting the parent to bring back the first `li`, right now it is finding the `ul` of an `li` as the top level container then has within it several other `ul` so the logic is working as written.

```
$(".menu li a").click(function() {
    return !($(this).parents("li:first").find("ul").toggle().length)
});
```

Comment: sorry, I don't understand. Can you give full example?

Comment: @Happy That is a full example, just replace your javascript snippet with the one I provided should behave the way you want. I edited the JSFiddle link to reflect this: http://jsfiddle.net/bXbnW/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bXbnW/2/ - the same problem, link should be clickable, when there is no child <ul> inside current <li>.

Comment: @Happy I'm sorry I misunderstood, updated the JSFiddle example.. should work as you expect now - http://jsfiddle.net/bXbnW/4/

Answer (score 1):

To perform an action if there's a child `ul` of the currently-hovered `li`:

```
$('li').hover(
  function(){
    if ($(this).has('ul')) {
      // do stuff
    }
  });
```

Comment: must be a click event, not hover.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bXbnW/1/ links inside other <li> (where is no child <ul>) should be clickable. They don't work with your solution, how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

I was going to add that you could also just use the `:has` selector with a `parent > child` selector ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bXbnW/5/)):

```
$('.menu li:has(ul) > a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
    return false;
});
```